# How to delete a word from my list using an algorithm?

Tags: c#, list, algorithm

I am doing a project and need help figuring out how to delete a word from my list. I have a bunch of scenarios I have to do and this is one of them. I have to implement a .DeleteWord("hello") function. Any ideas? Here is my code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> words = new List<string>();

    words.Add("car");
    words.Add("caramael");
    words.Add("hey");
    words.Add("hello");
    words.Add("helloeverybody");
    words.Add("CSC204");

    // Console.WriteLine("Scenario 1:");
    // Console.WriteLine();
    // foreach (string word in words)
    // {
    //      Console.WriteLine(word);
    //  }

    foreach (string word in words.GetWordsForPrefix("he"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nScenario 5 Printing all words:");
    words.Sort();

    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(word);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n Scenario 6 Insert  \"car\":");
    int index = words.BinarySearch("car");
    if (index < 0)
    {
        words.Insert(~index, "car");
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error, This word already exsits");
    }
}
```

Comment: See [List<T>.Remove(T) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.remove?view=net-5.0).

Comment: words.Remove(string) the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to implement a .DeleteWord("hello") function.

As far as I can get from your question you need a function that removes an element from the list if it already exists in the list. Here is a code snippet for that purpose:

```
    public static void RemoveWord(List<string> wordList, string word)
    {
        wordList.Remove(word);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In case you are not allowed to use built-in functions, you can loop through the list and delete the required item. There is pitfall that you must avoid: When deleting an item, the indexes of the following items and the list count will be decreased by 1 . Therefore it is best to loop backwards.

```
for (int i = list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (list[i] meets some condition) {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

If you want to delete only the first occurrence, you can leave the loop with `break` and don't have to care about this index problem and you can loop forwards

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++) {
    if (list[i] meets some condition) {
        list.RemoveAt(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: `RemoveAt` is a built in function

Comment: You are right, you can't do it completely without, but is quite elementary for a list compared to `Remove`. Otherwise, you would have to implement a list yourself based on arrays. Note that the question was explicitly about an algorithm. It's an opportunity for the OP to learn something.

Comment: Hum, if so perhaps an array-based  solution is an even better opportunity :-)